Como reabrir una conexión cerrar con AWS lambda y sequelize
Estoy creando una Lambda que hace una petición a una base de datos de Oracle y, como es una acción específica que no se manda a llamar siempre, estoy utilizando una Lambda. Ahora, mi problema es que la primera vez que llamo la Lambda, sí me muestra la información correctamente, pero cuando vuelvo a llamarla me salta el siguiente error:
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed!",
    "stack": [
        "Error: ConnectionManager.getConnection was called after the connection manager was closed!",
        "    at OracleConnectionManager.getConnection (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:70:13)",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:305:111",
        "    at /var/task/node_modules/retry-as-promised/dist/index.js:59:25",
        "    at new Promise (<anonymous>)",
        "    at retryAsPromised (/var/task/node_modules/retry-as-promised/dist/index.js:48:12)",
        "    at Sequelize.query (/var/task/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:300:12)",
        "    at fetchOC (file:///var/task/src/fetch.js:7:38)",
        "    at runRequest (file:///var/task/node_modules/@middy/core/index.js:166:9)"
    ]
}

Esto pasa la segunda vez que intento obtener información. Segun veo es porque la lamnbda intenta realizar la conexión, pero esta ya es rechazada porque sé cerro previamente
Ahora, mi código es el siguiente:
export const handler = middy()
    .use(verifyParams())
    .use(validateToken())
    .use({
        after: () => {
            sequelize.close();
        },
    })
    .handler(fetchData);

Donde fetchData es quien se encarga de realizar la petición, y after, quien se encarga de realizar el cierre de conexión.
Entonces, no sé si tendría que realizar el cierre o no, y, si se realiza el cierre, ¿cómo podría volver a reabrir la conexión?
Estoy utilizando lo siguiente:
Serverless: 4.4.7
middy:5.5.1
oracledb: 6.6.0
sequelize: 6.37.5
